# Is there a GUI test automation tool that hooks into the Apple iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, monkeytalk, system-testing, squish

I need to automate opening and closing of an application, be able to manipulate and verify component functionality within the app, and be able to modify configuration data in the iOS Settings. I think I already know the answer to this one, but is there any testing tool that can handle these requirements? Is Squish and its ilk capable of doing this on an Android OS?

Answer (score 0):

Squish is now capable of automating opening and closing of applications on iOS as well as Android. I don't know if that was the case back in 2013 when you asked this, but I am going through all unanswered Squish questions now.